# URL routing requires /Home/Page?page=1 instead of /Home/Page/1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url, seo, maproute

I am trying to build my ASP.NET MVC 4.5 project to use search engine friendly URLs. I am using the following route mapping.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{title}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, title = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

The intention is so that I can create URLs like this:

> Mysite.com/Home/Page/1/this-title-bit-is-just-for-show

but it fails and I have to use URLs like this:

> Mysite.com/Home/Page?page=1

In case it matters, the Controller Action that this link points to is below:

```
public ActionResult Page(int page)
{
    PostModel pm = new PostModel(page);
    return View(pm);
}
```

And I am generating URLs like this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Page", "Home", new { page = 1 })">1</a>
```

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Change the method to `public ActionResult Page(int id)` or change the route to `url: "{controller}/{action}/{page}/{title}",` And note that only the last parameter can be marked as `UrlParameter.Optional`

Comment: uh... you're asking an on-topic SEO-tagged question?  That's gotta be wrong.  Somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Page", "Home", new { page = 1 })">1</a>
```

Use

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Page", "Home", new { id = 1 })">1</a> //instead of page use id here
```

and change action method as shown :-

```
public ActionResult Page(int id) //instead of page use id here
{
    PostModel pm = new PostModel(id);
    return View(pm);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this fixed it :)